# Why do I keep getting told my variable is outside the function? Python

Tags: python

This is a part of something larger, but my problem is that I keep getting told by the shell that '"return" out of function'. I've tried removing indents and moving it around but it wont go away. Code:

```py
def worklodge_cost():
    if workshop == 1:  # what number the user puts in determines what values they get out of this workshop section
        price = 1000
        amtdays = 3
    elif workshop == 2:
        price = 800
        amtdays = 3
    elif workshop == 3:
        price = 1600
        amtdays = 3
    elif workshop == 4:
        price = 500
        amtdays = 1
    # print("This is your registration fee $", price)

    if location == 1:  # what number the user puts in determines the price of their lodging
        lodgeprice = 150
    elif location == 2:
        lodgeprice = 225
    elif location == 3:
        lodgeprice = 175
    elif location == 4:
        lodgeprice = 300
        totalodging = amtdays * lodgeprice  # taking the amount of days for the workshop and multiplying it by the lodging price of the location
        return totalodging
main()
```

Comment: ```def worklodge_cost(workshop): ``` pass the value of workshop in function and when you call that function add that in also

Comment: Can you make sure the indents in your code are shown correctly here? usually, this error occurs when something is not indented right

Comment: As a different note, you can change your code into two lines if you use a python dictionary. That should help with detecting tab/indent issues.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the return is placed outside a function.
The return needs to be placed INSIDE a function. Return is usually placed at the end of a function, see below.

```py
def lodgeprice(location, amtdays):
    if location == 1: #what number the user puts in determines the price of their lodging
        lodgeprice = 150
    elif location == 2:
        lodgeprice = 225
    elif location == 3:
        lodgeprice = 175
    elif location == 4:
        lodgeprice = 300
    totalodging = amtdays * lodgeprice #taking the amount of days for the workshop and multiplying it by the lodging price of the location
    return totalodging
```

Generally it seems like your code is in need of major refactoring. Consider what use the return would have in your code, is it at all necessary?.
I also suggest breaking your code down into functions, this makes it generally easier to handle.